# How to count 2D int array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Say for example I had the following:

```
    int[][] courses = {
            {1, 0},
            {2, 0},
            {3, 1},
            {3, 2},
    };
```

Now don't the first index represents x, and second index represents y? For example, courses[x][y], so courses[0][1], should print 2, but actually prints 0, why is that?

Comment: Because x=0 is the first index, so it gets the {1,0} , then y=1 is the second index and that gets you the 0.

Comment: You should declare your array as `{{1,2,3,3},{0,0,1,2}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2D array is actually an array whose elements are arrays.

The first index of the array is the index of the outer-most array.

Therefore `courses[0]` returns the inner array `{1, 0}` (the first element of the outer array) and `courses[0][1]` returns the second element of that array, which is `0`.

`courses[1][0]` would return `2`.

> Now don't the first index represents x, and second index represents y

If you treat a 2D array as a matrix, and by `x` you mean column index and by `y` you mean row index, then actually it's the other way around - the first index is the row index (y) and the second index is the column index (x).

Answer (score 0):

`courses[0,0]=1 courses[0,1]=0` - this is the first row

`courses[1,0]=2 courses[1,1]=0` - this is the second row

`courses[2,0]=3 courses[2,1]=1` - this is the third row